# Is there any method for folding a Hamiltonian matrix to lower dimension?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, eigenvalue, tight-binding

I want to solve a tight-binding Hamiltonian which is $6\times6$. I'm only interested in two of the six bands which lie near zero energy at $\vec{k}=(0,\frac{4\pi}{3\sqrt{3}a})$. Is there any way to write an effective Hamiltonian for these two bands or in other words, to only extract the details of these two bands?
$$
H=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -t_{12} & -t_{13} & 0 & 0 & -t_{16} e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{a_2}} \\
-t_{12}^* & 0 & 0 & -t_{24} & -t_{25} e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{a_1}} & 0 \\
-t_{13}^* & 0 & 0 & -t_{34} e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot (\vec{a_2}+\vec{a_1})} & -t_{35} & 0 \\
0 & -t_{24}^* & -t_{34}^* e^{i \vec{k} \cdot (\vec{a_2}+\vec{a_1})} & 0 & 0 & -t_{46}\\
0 & -t_{25}^* e^{-i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{a_1}} & -t_{35}^* & 0 & 0 & -t_{56}\\
-t_{16}^* e^{i \vec{k} \cdot \vec{a_2}} & 0 & 0 & -t_{46}^* & -t_{56}^* & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $t_{ij}s$ are the hopping parameters and the $\vec{a_1},\vec{a_2}$ are the bravais primitive vectors.